# How do I set a statement to print if an invalid zip file is entered?

Tags: java, zip

In my code currently I have a zip file which is printing my methods currently when entered, but if my Zip file is entered wrong or just does not exist I want to print `"File name expected.\n" + "Program ending.");` I want to make this an if else statement but I do not know what to exactly put in the if statement.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Buyer2App {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      
      BuyerProcessor object = new BuyerProcessor();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      object.readBuyerFile(in.nextLine());
      
      if (????) {
         System.out.print(object.generateReport());
         System.out.print(object.generateReportByName());
      System.out.print(object.generateReportByTotalPurchases());
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("File name expected as command line argument.\n"
               + "Program ending.");
      }
   }
```

Comment: [`File#exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#exists()) and I might also consider [`File#isFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#isFile())

Answer (score 0):

### try catch

you could use a `try-catch` block for operation, where it is not guaranteed to work:

```
try{
    object.readBuyerFile(in.nextLine());
    //if the operation from line above will not work, then an exception is thrown and the code is stopped - it will continue in the catch block then 
    System.out.print(object.generateReport());
    System.out.print(object.generateReportByName());
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("File name expected as command line argument.\n"
               + "Program ending.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways something that sounds simple like reading a file can fail. As MadProgrammer suggests, we can use File methods to check whether it is valid.
I have provided a more complete solution:

```java
// Buyer2App.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BuyerProcessor object = new BuyerProcessor();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    object.readBuyerFile(in.nextLine());

    if (!object.fileExists()) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.\nProgram ending.");
        in.close();
        return;
    }
    if (!object.fileCanRead()) {
        System.out.println("File cannot be read.\nProgram ending.");
        in.close();
        return;
    }
    // file is valid if the runtime has reached this point
    try {
        System.out.print(object.generateReport());
        System.out.print(object.generateReportByName());
        System.out.print(object.generateReportByTotalPurchases());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read reports from the file.\nProgram ending.");
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

// BuyerProcessor.java
private File file;

public void readBuyerFile(String fileName) {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
}

public boolean fileExists() {
    return file.exists();
}

public boolean fileCanRead() {
    return file.canRead();
}
```

The key here is to **not** have the `main` method throw any Exception, so that any compile-time Exception will force the programmer to write a `catch` block for it.

There are more ways to improve the design, but hopefully this answers your question.